# Calculate a ratio from part of a range.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm building a smartphone javascript application but my question today is really only math related. To give you a quick idea of what I'm doing, my code checks the smartphone's gyroscope to determine how much it is rotated. Based on that rotation, it's supposed to pan a background image around. So in the image below, the red box is stationary, while the photo is supposed to pan around in the background as you rotate your device.

[image]

Anyway, here's the math problem (focusing only on moving the X axis):

- The gyroscope gives a reading of 0 to 360
- The photo in the background gets moved from the top left, so its max and min values are 0 to -100
- Therefore the formula for how much to move the image based on the device rotation would be a simple ratio: (Gyroscope Reading * -100)/360
- **However**, I don't want people to need to turn their device all the way over to achieve the full animation, so I'm only interested in the gyroscope readings of about 140 to 220.
- So, what formula would achieve 140 = 0 and 220 = -100? The formula should maintain the ratio for all points in between.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500027/percentage-to-absolute-value-within-another-range/500072#500072 also note that we have $220-140$ and $0-(-100)$ involved, and the only trick may be determining which direction to pan upon a given movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a line that goes through $(140,0)$ and $(220,-100)$.  The [two point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) says it is $y-0=\frac {-100-0}{220-140}(x-140)$.  $x$ is the gyro, $y$ the output.  I left the constants so you could match them up with the equation in case you want to change them in the future.

Comment: Yes, a formula like that is what I need. I do need Y to be on one side by its self as a result though. Can you modify that?

Comment: You just have to add the constant (here $0$) to both sides.