# Calculate percentage out of difference of values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I want to create a progressbar which progress (in %) is influenced by the time between a timestamp in the past.

Timestamp one would be 1382377800.

Timestamp two would be 1382377860

Those are 60 seconds. The first one should represent 0%, the other one 100%.

I know I have to divide it somehow and multiply it, but can't figure it out.

1382377830 should be 50% then :i

Comment: Try $1382377800+0.5 (1382377860-1382377800)$. Adjust $0.5$ accordingly...

Comment: I am sorry but the result is not what I wanted. I want to get a percentage like 0.5, not a real number.

Comment: Hmm, you need to do a little work here. Try $\frac{1382377830-1382377800}{1382377860-1382377800}$.

Comment: Consider [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500027/percentage-to-absolute-value-within-another-range/500072#500072) as well.

Answer (score 1):

To find the percentage of 60 you've progressed past timestamp 1, simply subtract timestamp 1 from timestamp 2 to find the elapsed time and divide by 60. so:
$$p = \frac{(T2 - T1)}{60}$$

Where T1 is the first timestamp, T2 is the second, and p is the percentage you're looking for.